# Is the following map a continuous map between two Lie groups?

Tags: lie-groups, smooth-manifolds

Consider $GL_n(\mathbb{C})$ as a real Lie group, and $U_n(\mathbb{c})$ a real Lie subgroup of $GL_n(\mathbb{C})$. Consider map $\varphi$:
$$
\varphi : GL_n(\mathbb{C}) \longrightarrow GL_n(\mathbb{C}) 
$$
$$
X \longrightarrow XX^*
$$
Map which sends $X \rightarrow X^*$ is continuous, and real differentiable, but it's not complex differentiable, so $\varphi$ is continuous. Is it correct? If it's correct, then $U_n(\mathbb{C})$ is kernel of $\varphi$, then it's closed subgroup of real Lie group $GL_n(\mathbb{C})$, so it's real Lie subgroup of $GL_n(\mathbb{C})$?

Comment: It sounds a bit weird to call $U_n (\mathbb C)$ the kernel of $\varphi$, when $\varphi$ is not a group homomorphism.

Comment: @ArcticChar yes, it's weird. Better just say $U_n(\mathbb{C}) = \varphi ^{-1}(Id)$

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Yes, it is correct. But there is no need to mention differentiability here. Just say that $\varphi$ is the product of the continuous maps $X\mapsto X$ and $X\mapsto X^*$.